Have an error: "Column with id 'id' does not exist." by @tanstack/vue-table (vue3)
I have a red error in a Browser console when creating a table by @tanstack/vue-table. It is error is not critical. If I change 'name' -> 'id' - do not have an error, but I do not need to show 'id' in my table from data). How can I hide/fix 'Column with id 'id' does not exist.' error?
My settings from official docs:
const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<any>();
const columns = [
  columnHelper.accessor('name', {
    header: 'Name'
  }),
];


it's unclear what your case is. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It needs to be reproducible by other users. There are official demos from the vendor, e.g. https://stackblitz.com/github/tanstack/table/tree/main/examples/vue/basic

got same issue with react after updating to latest.

You can define the id column in your columns array and hide it from the table UI by setting an empty Fragment () => <></> to header and cell. This way, you can still access its value without displaying it.
const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<any>();

const columns = [
  columnHelper.accessor('id', {
    header: () => <></>,
    cell: () => <></>,
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor('name', {
    header: 'Name'
  }),
];

